I’m trying to make my planets atmosphere 46% inert Argon gas, but how would my creatures breath it? And what would their blood be like?
Argon is my favorite thing, I wish I could kiss it. So I am using it in my planets atmosphere. Here is a list of what is in its atmosphere:

Argon ($\mathrm{Ar}$) - 46%
Nitrogen ($\mathrm{N}_2$) - 42.66%
Oxygen ($\mathrm{O}_2$) - 11.44%
Carbon Dioxide ($\mathrm{CO}_2$) - 0.022%
Neon ($\mathrm{Ne}$) - 0.001%
Helium ($\mathrm{He}$) - 0.0003%
Methane ($\mathrm{CH}_4$) - 0.0001%
Krypton ($\mathrm{Kr}$) - 0.00007%
Hydrogen ($\mathrm{H}_2$) - 0.00003%
Xenon ($\mathrm{Xe}$) - 0.000005%
Ozone ($\mathrm{O_3}$) - 0.000004%
Nitrous Oxide ($\mathrm{N_2O}$) - 0.00002%
Carbon Monoxide ($\mathrm{CO}$) - 0.000005%
Ammonia ($\mathrm{NH_3}$) - Trace amounts
Sulfur Dioxide ($\mathrm{SO_2}$) - Trace amounts
Nitrogen Dioxide ($\mathrm{NO_2}$) - Trace amounts
Chlorofluorocarbons (CFCs) - Trace amounts
Radon ($\mathrm{Rn}$) - Trace amounts
Water Vapor ($\mathrm{H_2O}$) - Varies (around 0.25% on average, but up to 4% in humid conditions)
Hydrogen Peroxide ($\mathrm{H_2O_2}$) - Trace amounts

But how would my creatures breathe with that much inert gas in the air? And what would their blood be like? With the blood I am thinking that their veins would be made of biopolymers. And instead of iron, they would have nickel witch bonds with glycocalyx, and that instead of water their blood would have liquid nitrogen. What do you all think?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It is nothing unusual. Atmospheric nitrogen is similarly inert as argon - although there are some organism capable to process it, these are some fungi in the soil and not we. For us, if the 79% of $N_2$ in our atmosphere is $N_2$ or $Ar$, is nothing difference.
Other things what I see:

Ozone is very instable, it would quickly decay. There is no known way to stabilize it, despite the large research efforts.
Nitrogen oxydes would build quickly various acids with the water (rain) and leave the atmosphere.
Most stable radon isotope decays in 3-4 days. You need something which replenishes it, or it will be trace of lead in the soil.
Sulfur oxide will go as sulfuric acid into the rain,
$NH_3$ solves very well in water, also that will go in the soil with the rain.

What remains, will be very similar to our current atmosphere, with only about half so many oxygen content. Also that is nothing unusual - millions of humans live in similar environments, like in the about 4000m heigh Bolivian capital, La Paz.

Extension after knowing that you are thinking about liquid nitrogene blood. Boiling point of argon is -185C, which is a little bit even higher as the nitrogene (-198C). But neon is much more in the Universe as argon. Our Earth has only so little neon because it has escaped. But in such a cold planet, maybe it could have remained more. The boiling point of the neon is already only -246C, so you can have liquid nitrogen or argon in a neon atmosphere.

But, liquid nitrogen for blood? At a similar temperature to the atmosphere?

@Escapeddentalpatient. Argon boiling point is about there the nitrogene is.

But not where CO, CO2 and  methane's are.

@Escapeddentalpatient. CO is roughly the same, CO2 is much higher, that sublimes at about -70C. To have liquid CO, Ar, N2 in an atmosphere, I think that atmosphere should be neon.

Umm no. I want Purple storms, NOT ORANGE

@BoppickMan10 Some vaporized argon could still exist in the atmosphere, similarly as also we have a lot of water vapor in the atmosphere. Beside that, gases typically refract blue light more, making the sun yellow and the sky blue. Both effects push the orange neon to the blue / purple direction.

They would breathe "normally".
You already stated that argon is inert; dinitrogen is also inert. An Earth animal would happily breathe in that atmosphere, hadn't it been filled with nitrogen oxides to the point that it became lethal. There are actually breathing gasses for divers made up of such inert gasses such as argox (argon and oxygen) or, more similar to your atmosphere, trimix (He, N2, & O2).
The 11% oxygen concentration at 1.45 atm is somewhat interesting. Not all organisms would suffocate in that air since that's about 3 fourths of the partial pressure of oxygen on earth at sea level, a crane for example flies at an altitude of 30000' where the oxygen partial pressure is only a third of what is at sea level. So in conclusion, high flying birds can breathe on your planet for a little while before they are killed by the nitrogen oxides, and as for your blood question, it's kind of self-evident at this point.
Off topic: You're gonna have to think of a way for your planet to make a lot of that ozone since those trace amounts of CFCs will get at it very, very quickly. Your creatures will have their genetic code shredded and would have to move to Bikini Bottom, which makes your question irrelevant.

Thanks for the feed back also I’m asking WHAT MY CREATURES LUNGS WOULD BE BUILT FROM not ANYTHING about my atmosphere

Even on Earth, ozone isn't really that significant for blocking UV.  Yes, O3 does absorb more UV than O2, but not that much more. And if you brought the entire "ozone layer" down to sealevel it would be about 1 to 2 mm thick. It does make a difference, but compared to 10 miles of troposphere you'd hardly notice if it were gone. Meanwhile, O2 absorbing UV is what turns it into O3. So if CFCs destroy the O3 (which there's some question about how they'd get up there since nearly all of them are heavier than air) then it just results in more UV being absorbed by O2, which creates more O3.
